# How to handle dynamic number of inputs from html form with with Revel Golang

Tags: html, forms, go, revel

I have an html form with dynamic number of inputs. Each input must be a Model object, and i also have a function, which receives values from this inputs.
My html form:

```
<form action="{{url "Votes.CreateVote"}}" id="formVoteCreate" method="POST">
            <p class="field">
                <label>Question:</label>
                <input type="text" name="question" size="40"  />
            </p>
             <div ng-repeat="answer in answers">
                <p class="field">
                    <label>//stuff.title//:</label>
                    <input type="text" name=//stuff.name// size="40"  />
                </p>
             </div>
            <p>
                <input ng-click="addInput()" class="btn"  type="button" value="Add answer">
            </p>
            <p class="buttons">
                <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </form>
```

And revel golang handler:

```
func (c Votes) CreateVote() revel.Result {
   // in this place i want get a slice with answers from html form
   return c.Redirect(routes.App.Index())
}
```

and answer model:

```
type Answer struct {
  Model
  Text    string
}
```

How can i send form's values as a slice with answers packed to Model?

Answer (score 1):

Each Revel controller comes with an attached `Request`, which is really just a normal Go standard library [`Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request). As such, this is the same as for plain Go web servers, in that we cannot use the `Request.Form.Get("inputname")` method, as this would only give the first result. Instead, we need to access the values in the `Form` map directly:

```
package controllers

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/robfig/revel"
)

type App struct {
    *revel.Controller
}

func (c App) Index() revel.Result {
    if err := c.Request.ParseForm(); err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    values := c.Request.Form["text"]
    for i := range values {
        log.Println(values[i])
    }
    return c.Render()
}
```

The example above is for a simple application like the one generated by Revel when you start a project, with an input named `text`, and can be adapted to your specific case.

The `values` variable is of type `[]string`, which is why the following is logged, if you submit a GET request with query string `?text=value1&text=value2&text=value3`, as would happen for a form with `method="GET"` and three text inputs with `name="text"`:

```
2016/03/07 22:16:41 app.go:19: value1
2016/03/07 22:16:41 app.go:19: value2
2016/03/07 22:16:41 app.go:19: value3
```

The form in the question happens to use method POST, but the code for reading the values from the form remains the same.